# How to get my code always get in the middle on the Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript

I'm new in the programmer's world and I'm a student in the 1st degree at the University of Brussels. So my question is: how do I manage to put my code always in the middle of the screen even when resizing it?

---

### The problem I'm confronting right now is that I have to make a t-shirt design as a task for my course of javascript.

```js
/*************
* my context *
*************/

'use strict';
/** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
let context;

getCanvasContext();

function getCanvasContext() {
    //get a reference to the canvas element and configure it to fill the whole window
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.style.margin = 0;
    canvas.style.padding = 0;
    canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    canvas.style.top = 0;
    canvas.style.left = 0;
    //get drawing context
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

export default context;
```

```js
/*********
*my utils*
**********/

'use strict';

import context from "./context";

/**
 * @param {number} h the hue in degrees
 * @param {number} s the saturation in percentage
 * @param {number} l the lightness in percentage
 */
export function hsl(h, s, l) {
    return 'hsl(' + h + "," + s + "%," + l + '%)';
}

/**
 * @param {number} r red (8bits, number between 0-255)
 * @param {number} g green (8bits, number between 0-255)
 * @param {number} b blue (8bits, number between 0-255)
 */
export function rgb(r, g, b) {
    return 'rgb(' + r + "," + g + "," + b + ')';
}

export function degrees(degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}
export function fillCircle(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAgnle) {

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAgnle);
    context.fill();
}

export function circle(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAgnle) {

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAgnle);
    context.stroke();

}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="t-shirt.js" type="module"></script>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="resources/TShirt.png" />
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

---

[My t-shirt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NxxN.png)

---

I just need your help to understand and learn from others.

**Thanks already for your answers and your time and
I apologize for my bad English, but I will try to do my best.**

Comment: Sadly, because this is the web world, we have to ask what browser this needs to work in as there are various solutions based on what you need to target.

Comment: So you need to render your the T-Shirt image into the canvas then add a shape in the center of that image right ? and that image need to expand all the available screen space or it's just the image size ?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your response. I only needed to work on chrome. And the image is only an image putted in a html file with text align center. So from that i have to get my js code to be the most responsive. For the moment even when i resize a little bit my screen size evrything moves all around and dont stay int the middle. i tried to get a link to my github file but i really new to this world so i doesn't know how it really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with CSS, but it looks like you need a JavaScript solution (since it is a JavaScript course). You can do this by taking `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` and dividing them by 2 to get half of the screen width. Then, apply this to any element that needs to be centered. Here is an example.

---

**EDIT:** Whoops, I didn't know you were using the `<canvas>` element. You can simply get the width and height of the canvas by using `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` and dividing those values by 2. This should get the center of the canvas. Currently, there is no way to detect a canvas resize in JavaScript. Instead, use a loop that updates the element every `x` miliseconds.

```
setInterval(function(){
    update();
}, x);
```